# ArrayList from servlet to JSP

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, jstl

could someone tell me why this is is not working? the following servlet code consists of listing files that are present within a directory:

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException,IOException{

        String file = "/Library/Tomcat/webapps/HelloServlet/src";
        File f = new File(file);

        ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(f.list()));


        request.setAttribute("fileNames", names);


        RequestDispatcher rd = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("main.jsp");  
        rd.forward(request, response);
}
```

The next sequence of code present in the JSP intends to print this list, however it's not working:

```
<%@ page import="java.text.*,java.util.*" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@page import="java.util.List"%>
<%@page import="java.util.ArrayList"%>
<%@page import="java.util.Arrays"%>


<c:forEach var="files" items="${fileNames}" >
${files}
</c:forEach>
```

If somebody could help me it would be great, been stuck on this for over a day now!

Comment: Are you getting any error? Also, can you print the value of `names` before adding it to the `request` object?

Comment: No none! It's really confusing me, when i use the jstl tag ${fileNames} for a string it works fine, but when its an ArrayList i get nothing...

Comment: As a side note instead of `jstl` on your jsp you can simply fetch the attribute from the request object using `request.getAttribute("fileNames")` in this case you wouldn't need the list itself.

Comment: Print out `<% request.getAttribute("fileNames"); %>` in your jsp

Comment: Do you see anything relevant in the server logs?

Comment: Try to change file path and test. May be the application not able to access your specified path.

Answer (score 0):

i'm ot sure where is the mistake, but let me write what could be, first check the link

```
 String file = "/Library/Tomcat/webapps/HelloServlet/src";
```

your adding a File f but there is no file specified....maybe you are missing the file.

in Jsp my advice always check if its null, and you can user `requestScope` to get your `setAttribute`, use `varStatus=""` too.

```
<c:if test="${requestScope.fileNames!= null}">
<c:forEach var="files" items="${requestScope.fileNames}" varStatus="loop" >
${files}
</c:forEach>
</c:if>
```

I wish i was helpful.